# how to find what jvm options idea is using on mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I've changed `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea13/idea.vmoptions`, but am not sure it was picked as I see in top that the `idea` process is not using as much memory as expected. How can I find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique applies for any java application running local or remote.

1. Start IntelliJ.
2. Run [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) found in you JDK (such as C:\Program
   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\jvisualvm.exe).
3. When this useful tool starts look at the list of running java application under the
   "Local" tree node.
4. Double click IntelliJ IDEA (pid [n]).
5. On the right side there will be inspection contents in tab for the 
   application. In the middle of the Overview tab you will see the JVM
   arguments for the application.

jvisualvm can be found in any JDK since JDK 6 Update 7.  Video tutorial on jvisualvm is [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8n7Bg7-A4I)